# Fortran compiler indicates invalid expression

Tags: fortran

I am having 2 compiler errors on this function called `kawa`.

The first error is on the first line, saying

> error 471 - Invalid item(s) in argument list

I think that I am supposed to write `function kawa(dd,ee,owari2,r,t,ttt,s,at12)` instead.

The second error is on the line

> t(i)=0

saying invalid argument on the left

I tried the following:

1. `t(i)=0.0` , but it still failed.
2. declare `t` as double precision in the main program.

   ```
   function kawa(dd,ee,owari2,r(all),t(all),ttt(all),s(all),at12(all))
   integer m,i 
    double precision denmin, denmax,sumgosa,alfa,sumgosa3
    double precision w(250),nmax(250),ice(250),bata(250)
    double precision sumw,sumr,fw,sumdp,batat,gosa,sumfw
    double precision ttt(250)
    double precision dp(250),den(250),k(250),n
    denmin=dd
   denmax=0.5
   sumgosa=0
   alfa=ee
    do i=0, owari2,+1
    w(i)=r(i)
    if(t(i)<0) then 
     t(i)=0
      else
    ttt(i)=tttt(i)+2
    endif
    if(ttt(i)<0) then 
     ttt(i)=0
      else
         k(i)=((denmin+(denmax-denmin)*t(i)/3)/denmin)**2.0      
     nmax(i)=denmax*denmax/denmin/denmin-k(i)
       ice(i)=r(i)
     endif
    if(at(i)>2)then 
        ice(i)=0
    else
          bata(i)=alfa*ttt(i)
   end if
   enddo

   sumfw=0 
   sumr=0 
   do m=0, owari2,+1
     fw=0
     sumdp=0 
     sumw=0 
     sumr=0 
     i=m 
     batat=bata(i)
        do i=m,0,-1
       n=m-i
       if(ice(i)-batat<=0) then 
         dp(i)=0 
         fw=w(i)+fw
         w(i)=0
         batat=batat-ice(i)
         ice(i)=0
         else if(n>nmax(i)) then
                 dp(i)=(ice(i)-batat)/denmax
                 else
                 dp(i)=(ice(i)-batat)/denmin*((k(i)+n)**0.5)
                 ice(i)=ice(i)-batat
                 batat=0 
                 den(i)=(w(i)+fw)/dp(i)
                 w(i)=w(i)+fw
                 fw=0
                 endif
                 if(den(i)>denmax) then
                    den(i)=denmax
                    fw=w(i)-dp(i)*denmax
                     w(i)=dp(i)*denmax
               endif 
    sumdp=sumdp+dp(i)
    sumw=sumw+w(i)
    sumr=sumr+r(i)
    enddo
    sumfw=sumfw+fw
    i=m 
    if(s(i)==32767)then 
      gosa=0
      goto 10
    else 
       gosa=(sumdp-s(i))*(sumdp-s(i))
     endif
     enddo        
    10 sumgosa =sumgosa+gosa 
   kawa=sumgosa**0.5

   end function kawa
   ```

Comment: Given that you seem to understand you are expected to use `kawa(dd,ee,owari2,r,t,ttt,s,at12)` rather than `kawa(dd,ee,owari2,r(all),t(all),ttt(all),s(all),at12(all)` I'm not sure that I follow your question.  The second error is a consequence of this incorrect statement of the arguments.

Comment: To get help, it will be useful to provide us with a [mcve]. Else: (i) You mention one fix but do not actually apply it, please fix it in your code and mention what error remain. (ii) The second error, as francescalus mentions, occurs because you do not respect the basic syntax of Fortran, it would be good to document yourself in a reference book or a tutorial.

Comment: Taking into account the quantity of variables and possibly your lack of experience with the language, I strongly advise you to use `implicit none`

Comment: You need to tell the compiler that `t` is an array. Use the advise of people who commented before me, it is helpful.